# How to check what cpu features can be used in my current system image?

Tags: julia, instruction-set

I found on the internet a performance tip for Julia: compile the system image for your architecture.

Besides the fact, that the process gives an error

```
julia> include(joinpath(Sys.BINDIR, Base.DATAROOTDIR, "julia", "build_sysimg.jl"))
julia> build_sysimg()
ERROR: UndefVarError: Libdl not defined
```

I am wondering, how to check all the supported instruction sets that my current system image is using? (i.e. can it use `avx2`?)

I use Julia 1.0.0

Comment: AFAIK, in Julia 1.0.0 it's not necessary for performance anymore to build a custom system image (at least on the common OSs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that Julia has an out-of-the box function for this, but if you add the [CpuId.jl package](https://github.com/m-j-w/CpuId.jl) via `]add CpuId` in the REPL, you can call `using CpuId; cpufeaturetable()`, as stated in their README.md.
(Note - we are in the process of upgrading it to 1.0 - so do file an issue/PR if you run into bugs.)

Comment: Cool, but how can I check the CPU features the current Julia image is compiled to support?